# How to no-indent section headings in scrrprt table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, koma-script, tocstyle

Using the `scrreprt` class of KOMA-Script with `xelatex`, I'd like to have my section entries in the table of contents appear without indenting. My current code is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,DIV12,BCOR8.25mm,twoside,parskip=half]{scrreprt}
% setup the table of contents
\usepackage[tocbreaksstrict]{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\settocfeature{raggedhook}{\raggedright}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{3em}
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{4em}
\makeatother
\KOMAoptions{toc=flat} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}
\end{document}
```

which results in the following output:

[image: Section heading normal toc]

However, I'd like to have the lines in the toc flush left with the rest.

Ideally, this would work with `tocstyle`, which most probably prohibits the use of `tocloft` to do this. The reason I'm using `tocstyle` is that it seems to get me best results in typesetting a very large table of contents of a ~2000 pages book with hundreds of sections. Many section titles used to extend into the right margin and push out the page numbers. This seems to be largely fixed by the two `\renewcommand` settings. However, I also needed the `\raggedright` to avoid the toc to be set in funny looking justified style. That's when `tocstyle` came into the game.

If there is need to change over to `tocloft`, I'm happy to do that provided it works with my long section titles not shown in the example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section{\bprot@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}}% no indentation
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{3em}
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{4em}
\makeatother
```

Comment: beautiful, spot on!

Comment: Note, the redefinition of `\l@section` is not longer recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The (key-value) KOMA option `toc=flat` is currently not recognized by `tocstyle`. Replace it with the `tocstyle` package option `tocflat`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,DIV12,BCOR8.25mm,twoside,parskip=half]{scrreprt}
% setup the table of contents
\usepackage[tocbreaksstrict,tocflat]{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\settocfeature{raggedhook}{\raggedright}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{3em}
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{4em}
\makeatother
% \KOMAoptions{toc=flat} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With an uptodate KOMA-Script version there is no need to load an additional package to use `\raggedright` for the section entries in ToC. This can be done by

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocraggedentrytext]{section}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,
  DIV=12,BCOR=8.25mm,% syntax has changed
  twoside,parskip=half,
  toc=flat
]{scrreprt}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocraggedentrytext]{section}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{3em}
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{4em}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First Section}
Text
\section{Second Section}
Text
\section{Third Section with a long title that needs more than one line in the table of contents}
Text
\end{document}
```